# Parent child tree structure in android

Tags: android, tree, parent-child

I need to display a parent child list view in which i need to display continents name/Country Name/ City or may go further inside from city.
So how can i display such structure in android.
Please help me.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You have to use expandable list view for this.

Comment: Try expandable listview...

Comment: [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: Thank You all..... I will try list Expandable list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), And for example go through [this](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html).....